# How can I compare partial paths in C#?

Tags: c#, path, compare

How can I compare a path in C#? I to need compare these two routes:

```
C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Archivos temporales de Internet

C:\Users\juanito\AppData\Local\Archivos temporales de Internet
```

Although different by the user, they are the same in everything else, so I need the code to recognize that they are equal.

I think in this

```
if (C:\Users\juanito\AppData\Local\Archivos temporales de Internet == C:\Users\ ..\AppData\Local\Archivos temporales de Internet)
{
    // great
}
```

but it doesn't work

Any help?

Thank you in advance

Comment: But why though? Hint; `Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%LOCALAPPDATA%\\Archivos temporales de Internet")`

Comment: Thanks, i don´t know if i doing something wrong, but at the time i compare, i get the local path @"C:\Users\administrator\AppData\Local\Archivos temporales de Internet"; and when i compare the path, this changed in the user depending the case @"C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Local\Archivos temporales de Internet"; and the code says its diferent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this can help

first, go to [regex101](https://regex101.com/) or other similar website to find out regex pattern by your test string

then will find out some pattern like
`C:\\Users\\(\w+)\\AppData\\Local\\Archivos\stemporales\sde\sInternet`

Second, use [.NET's Regex class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-6.0) to match string, and the [user] folder can use a regex pattern.

LIKE

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

// Regex can use as static class 
// and this will return a bool result that your pattern is matched or not
Regex.IsMatch(input, @"C:\\Users\\(\w+)\\AppData\\Local\\Archivos temporales de Internet");
```

then use the `IsMatch`'s bool result to compare these two string that are equal or not

a example with .NET 6 ConsoleApp

```
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Console.WriteLine("Start testing regex ...");

string testDataA = @"C:\Users\juanito\AppData\Local\Archivos temporales de Internet";
string testDataB = @"C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Local\Archivos temporales de Internet";
string testDataC = @"C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Archivos temporales de Internet";

if (IsMatchPattern(testDataA) == IsMatchPattern(testDataB))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Matched A == B");
}

if (IsMatchPattern(testDataA) == IsMatchPattern(testDataC))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Matched A == C");
}

if (IsMatchPattern(testDataB) == IsMatchPattern(testDataC))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Matched B == C");
}

static bool IsMatchPattern(string input)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(input, @"C:\\Users\\(\w+)\\AppData\\Local\\Archivos temporales de Internet");
}

Console.ReadLine();
```